# Many-to-one mapping and Struts2-jquery-grid

Tags: hibernate, struts2, many-to-one, jqgrid

I was checking the showcase for struts2-jquery-grid. I could understand how to send the List of my objects to the grid Model, but in the sample the object is simple, it has no attribute as an object. However in my case, my Model class looks like this :

```
public class Student(
 private String first_name;
 private String last_name;
 private Person father;
 private Person mother; // an attribute of another class

 // other attributes, getters and setters

}
```

In the sample, they have like this :

```
<s:url id="remoteurl" action="jsontable"/>
    <sjg:grid
        id="gridtable"
        caption="Customers Examples"
        dataType="json"
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        pager="true"
        gridModel="gridModel"
        rowList="10,15,20"
        rowNum="15"
        rownumbers="true"
        resizable="true"
        resizableAnimate="true"
        resizableGhost="true"
        resizableHandles="all"
    >
        <sjg:gridColumn name="id" index="id" title="ID" width="30" formatter="integer" sortable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="name" index="name" title="Name" width="250" sortable="true"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="country" index="country" title="Country" sortable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="city" index="city" title="City" sortable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="creditLimit" index="creditLimit" title="Credit Limit" align="right" formatter="currency" sortable="false"/>
    </sjg:grid>
  </div>
```

Please, any idea about how to show the ID of the father and the mother (Foreign key in my database )? Also, is it possible not to mention all the attributes?? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Look for examples of using the struts2-json-plugin particularly the _include_ and _exclude_ parameters. Although you should try to fetch close to what you need because it could be expensive to bring back more than necessary from the db. The service layer should dictate what can be retrieved.  As such there are two issues: 1) How go get what you need from the db and represent it (service layer in combination with db layer) and 2) The presentation of that data (using the struts2 json result). I dislike the struts2 jquery tags because they hide detail thus reducing help from the jquery community.

Answer (score 0):

If what I'm thinking is correct, you want to display the `Id` of the `father` property and the `Id` of the `mother` property. That means that `Person` object has an `Id` property. If this correct, you can do this;

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="father.id" index="father.id" title="Father Id" width="250" sortable="true"/>
<sjg:gridColumn name="mother.id" index="mother.id" title="Mother Id" width="250" sortable="true"/>
```

I think this will solve your problem.